# Comprehension of role(s) of 也 which is used inside 他有一些成绩，但也不应该骄傲。

Tags: grammar

> 他有一些成绩，但也不应该骄傲。

**My translation** : *He got some good achievements/grades, but he shouldn't be conceited.*

I've got the meaning "but also" translating directly 但也, but seems this translation doesn't fit in this case.

Nextly thought that adding 连 at the beginning of the sentence namely composing following.

**连**他有一些成绩，但**也**不应该骄傲。 : *Even he got some achievements/grades, he shouldn't be conceited*

I suspect this is also incorrect.

I want your wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

也 here means "still"

他有一些成绩(he got some  success)，但**也**不应该骄傲 (but **still** shouldn't be cocky)

Another way to look at 也(even)"

- 有一些成绩(也) = (even) got some  success
- 不应该骄傲  = shouldn't be cocky
- 有一些成绩(**也**)不应该骄傲 = shouldn't be cocky (**even**) got some  success

More examples:

> 打死我[也]不去

Will not go [even] if someone beat me to death

or

You can beat me to death and I [still] won't go

> 一年薪水[也]不夠買車

Not enough to buy a car [even] with a whole year's salary

or

A whole year's salary [still] isn't enough to buy a car